# Envio de Newsletter para e-mails em massa do banco - sem limite de e-mail SwiftMailer

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, newsletter

Oi,

Eu tenho uma ação no meu controlador que faz o disparo de e-mails do banco de dados. Eu fiz uns testes na minha máquina inserindo na tabela somente o meu próprio e-mail, botei até 1000. Eu só consegui recebe 750 e-mails na minha caixa. O que será que pode ser?

```
 $usuarios = Doctrine_Core::getTable('tbmailing')->createQuery('u')->select('u.email')->where('u.ativo = ?', 'Y')->execute();

    foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
    {
        $sair = '<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:x-small;">'
                . 'Se você deseja cancelar o recebimento deste boletim, '
                . '<a href="'.$rota.'/mailing/unsubscribe/'.base64_encode($usuario->getEmail()).'">'
                . 'acesse aqui.'
                . '</a>'
               . '</p>';

        $message = $this->getMailer()->compose(
            array("informacao@site.gov.br" => "Meu Site"),
                $usuario->getEmail(),
                'Meu Site',
                '<img src="http://www.meusite.gov.br/images/informativoHeader.jpg"/>'.
                '<br><br>'.
                $body
                .'<img src="http://www.meusite.gov.br/images/rodape.jpg" border="0"/>'
                .$sair
            );

        $message->setContentType("text/html");

        $this->getMailer()->send($message);
    }
```

Eu uso o SwiftMailer do Symfony framework, na versão 1.4.